# RuntimeError: "slow_conv2d_cpu" not implemented for 'Half'

Tags: pytorch

Within my python script I am using several ML libraries.
I am following a tutorial from YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTn1fXYw9sU) to create a voice assistant.

But after execution of the script I am getting these errors:

```
RuntimeError: "slow_conv2d_cpu" not implemented for 'Half'
```

This is the same error:
["RuntimeError: "slow_conv2d_cpu" not implemented for 'Half'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74725439/runtimeerror-slow-conv2d-cpu-not-implemented-for-half)

I am using a Lenovo Thinkpad T560 with an i5-6300 CPU with 2.4 GHz and 8G RAM. The graphics are from Intel and included, so I cannot change to CUDA in this system.

Answer (score 0):

This seems related to the following ussue: ["RuntimeError: "slow_conv2d_cpu" not implemented for 'Half'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74725439/runtimeerror-slow-conv2d-cpu-not-implemented-for-half)

the proposed solution that worked for me was:

```
options = whisper.DecodingOptions(fp16 = False)
```